# Remove ngrams with leading and trailing stopwords

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, quanteda

I want to identify major n-grams in a bunch of academic papers, including n-grams with nested stopwords, but not n-grams with leading or trailing stopwords.

I have about 100 pdf files. I converted them to plain-text files through an Adobe batch command and collected them within a single directory. From there I use R. (It's a patchwork of code because I'm just getting started with text mining.)

My code:

```
library(tm)
# Make path for sub-dir which contains corpus files 
path <- file.path(getwd(), "txt")
# Load corpus files
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(path), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain, language="en"))

#Cleaning
docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)

# Merge corpus (Corpus class to character vector)
txt <- c(docs, recursive=T)

# Find trigrams (but I might look for other ngrams as well)
library(quanteda)
myDfm <- dfm(txt, ngrams = 3)
# Remove sparse features
myDfm <- dfm_trim(myDfm, min_count = 5)
# Display top features
topfeatures(myDfm)
#                  as_well_as             of_the_ecosystem                  in_order_to         a_business_ecosystem       the_business_ecosystem strategic_management_journal 
#603                          543                          458                          431                          431                          359 
#in_the_ecosystem        academy_of_management                  the_role_of                the_number_of 
#336                          311                          289                          276
```

For example, in the top ngrams sample provided here, I'd want to keep "academy of management", but not "as well as", nor "the_role_of". I'd like the code to work for any n-gram (preferably including less than 3-grams, although I understand it's simpler in this case to just remove stopwords first).

Comment: Have a look at the examples section in `?quanteda::tokenize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how in **quanteda**: use `dfm_remove()`, where the pattern you want to remove is the stopword list followed by the concatenator character, for the beginning and end of the expression.  (Note here that for reproducibility, I have used a built-in text object.)

```
library("quanteda")

# remove for your own txt
txt <- data_char_ukimmig2010

(myDfm <- dfm(txt, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, ngrams = 3))
## Document-feature matrix of: 9 documents, 5,518 features (88.5% sparse).

(myDfm2 <- dfm_remove(myDfm, 
                     pattern = c(paste0("^", stopwords("english"), "_"), 
                                 paste0("_", stopwords("english"), "$")), 
                     valuetype = "regex"))
## Document-feature matrix of: 9 documents, 1,763 features (88.6% sparse).
head(featnames(myDfm2))
## [1] "immigration_an_unparalleled" "bnp_can_solve"               "solve_at_current"           
## [4] "immigration_and_birth"       "birth_rates_indigenous"      "rates_indigenous_british"
```

#### Bonus answer:

You can read your pdfs using the **readtext** package, which also works just fine with **quanteda** using the above code.

```
library("readtext")
txt <- readtext("yourpdfolder/*.pdf") %>% corpus()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the **corpus** R package, with *The Wizard of Oz* as an example (Project Gutenberg ID#55):

```
library(corpus)
library(Matrix) # needed for sparse matrix operations

# download the corpus
corpus <- gutenberg_corpus(55)

# set the preprocessing options
text_filter(corpus) <- text_filter(drop_punct = TRUE, drop_number = TRUE)

# compute trigram statistics for terms appearing at least 5 times;
# specify `types = TRUE` to report component types as well 
stats <- term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 3, min_count = 5, types = TRUE)

# discard trigrams starting or ending with a stopword
stats2 <- subset(stats, !type1 %in% stopwords_en & !type3 %in% stopwords_en)

# print first five results:
print(stats2, 5)
##    term               type1 type2 type3     count support
## 4  said the scarecrow said  the   scarecrow    36       1
## 7  back to kansas     back  to    kansas       28       1
## 16 said the lion      said  the   lion         19       1
## 17 said the tin       said  the   tin          19       1
## 48 road of yellow     road  of    yellow       12       1
## ⋮  (35 rows total)

# form a document-by-term count matrix for these terms
x <- term_matrix(corpus, select = stats2$term)
```

In your case, you can convert from the `tm` Corpus object with

```
corpus <- as_corpus_frame(docs)
```